# File Download using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, download

I'm trying to download a file using Python Selenium; trying to figure out a way to grab control of the yellow color generic download prompt that shows up at the bottom of the screen when you download a file. Is there a way to hit 'Save-As' using Selenium and save the file using Selenium and the same driver session.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and provide a detailed explanation of the problem, along with the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the problem and your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your driver download settings, for example with firefox. When a file is requested to download, it won't create a popup window, and will save in the location you specify below.

```
FirefoxProfile fxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();

fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList",2);
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",false);
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.download.dir","c:\\mydownloads");
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");

WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(fxProfile);
```

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome, firefox you can easily handle by changing the browser setting manually or by setting the preferences as shown in the example above.

```
fxProfile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk","text/csv");
```

I am not very sure of the python code to do it.
However, If you are using IE 11, there is no way of skipping the warning (yeah IE is hard to handle!!). In that case you need AutoIT to work on the console to click save.
Do pip install PyAutoIt. Following is the link to assist you on the same https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoIt/

Disadvantages of AutoIT :-

1. It requires console to be available on the machine.
2. During execution, focus must be on the same screen. You can use JSExecutor
   to execute the javascript with focus.

Let me know if anything else is needed on this.